# Lief won't install | couldn't build wheel for lief

Tags: python, macos, pip

I got lief working just fine on my Desktop (windows), but it refuses to install on my MacBook. I'm newer to Python development and installing new libraries, so maybe there's something I'm missing. I have Python 3.6 and 3.7 on my machine (is that a possible issue?). Lief appears to have support for Python 3.6, but I can't seem to install it using "pip install lief" or "pip3 install lief". I've updated setuptools but that doesn't seem to make any difference, either.

Terminal:

```
[Bens-MacBook-Pro-2:Downloads bluchterhand$ pip3 install lief
Collecting lief
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/0e/0d6f3357975dd1530aeb4b4a84a99d493775391758378fb5109f47b613f9/lief-0.9.0.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: lief
  Building wheel for lief (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-wheel-mme5acjc --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/lief
  copying lief/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/lief
  running build_ext
  Url: https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF/releases/download/0.9.0/lief-0.9.0-py3.6-osx.egg
  <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py", line 285, in <module>
      'sdist':     lief_sdist
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py", line 215, in build_extension
      self._install_from_source_package()
    File "/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py", line 265, in _install_from_source_package
      raise Exception("Unable to find {}".format(url))
  Exception: Unable to find /Users/bluchterhand/lief-0.9.0-py3.6-osx.egg

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lief
  Running setup.py clean for lief
Failed to build lief
Installing collected packages: lief
  Running setup.py install for lief ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-record-g3smg09m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/lief
    copying lief/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/lief
    running build_ext
    Url: https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF/releases/download/0.9.0/lief-0.9.0-py3.6-osx.egg
    <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py", line 285, in <module>
        'sdist':     lief_sdist
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
        self._build_extensions_serial()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py", line 215, in build_extension
        self._install_from_source_package()
      File "/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py", line 265, in _install_from_source_package
        raise Exception("Unable to find {}".format(url))
    Exception: Unable to find /Users/bluchterhand/lief-0.9.0-py3.6-osx.egg

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-record-g3smg09m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hp/ggfhzr7n133cr3csm59kdvs80000gn/T/pip-install-g3m0_dgi/lief/
```

Most notably; it fails to build the wheel. I've installed wheel many times thinking the install might've been broken, but I don't think that's the case anymore. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As with everything I ever post to this site, I found a solution to the problem the moment I posted. I downloaded the egg file from https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF/releases and pasted it in the /Users/NAME directory... all good. Gonna leave this up for anyone else having similar issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with everything I ever post to this site, I found a solution to the problem the moment I posted. I downloaded the egg file from github.com/lief-project/LIEF/releases and pasted it in the /Users/NAME directory... all good. Gonna leave this up for anyone else having similar issues...